# How do I read custom keyboard shortcut from user in WPF?

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, user-input

In my application, I want to let users customize keyboard shortcuts, just like it's done in Visual Studio's keyboard options. The user can focus a blank text box and then type any shortcut he wants to assign to a command.

The closest I've come to make it work is by subscribing to the TextBox.PreviewKeyDown event, setting it as handled to prevent actual text input in the text box. I then ignore the KeyDown events associated with modifier keys (is there a cleaner way to determine if a Key is a modifier key?).

```
// Code-behind
private void ShortcutTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // The text box grabs all input
    e.Handled = true;

    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || 
        e.Key == Key.RightCtrl || 
        e.Key == Key.LeftAlt ||
        e.Key == Key.RightAlt || 
        e.Key == Key.LeftShift ||
        e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        return;

    string shortcutText = "";
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        shortcutText += "Ctrl+";
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
        shortcutText += "Shift+";
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt)
        shortcutText += "Alt+";
    _ShortcutTextBox.Text = shortcutText + e.Key.ToString();

}
```

The above works for any shortcut starting with Ctrl and Ctrl+Shift, but fails for any Alt shortcuts. The e.Key is always set to `Key.System` when I press a shortcut containing Alt.

How can I record Alt shortcuts from the user? Is there a better, more robust way to record shortcuts form the user?

Comment: I have a feeling the Alt key is used by WPF to attempt capturing an Alt key combo to focus on a control which is tied to a label with a mnemonic shortcut (like Alt+F for the _File menu, or Alt+O for an _OK button). Maybe there's a way to prevent or override that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trick is to use the [SystemKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.systemkey.aspx) property if the [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key.aspx) property is set to `Key.System`:

```
private void ShortcutTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // The text box grabs all input.
    e.Handled = true;

    // Fetch the actual shortcut key.
    Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);

    // Ignore modifier keys.
    if (key == Key.LeftShift || key == Key.RightShift
        || key == Key.LeftCtrl || key == Key.RightCtrl
        || key == Key.LeftAlt || key == Key.RightAlt
        || key == Key.LWin || key == Key.RWin) {
        return;
    }

    // Build the shortcut key name.
    StringBuilder shortcutText = new StringBuilder();
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) {
        shortcutText.Append("Ctrl+");
    }
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0) {
        shortcutText.Append("Shift+");
    }
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != 0) {
        shortcutText.Append("Alt+");
    }
    shortcutText.Append(key.ToString());

    // Update the text box.
    _ShortcutTextBox.Text = shortcutText.ToString();
}
```

I added the left and right `Windows` keys to the modifier list, because they sometimes appeared in the shortcut key name when a complex (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt`) key combination was typed from a Terminal Server session. They're never present in `Keyboard.Modifiers`, though, since they're reserved for global shortcuts, so I don't handle them there.

I also used a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to avoid creating too many `string` instances.

This solution works with any key combination, except `Shift+Alt` (the `Alt` modifier is not seen in that case). That might be an artifact of my Terminal Server environment, though, so your mileage may vary.

Finally, I added a `_File` menu to the window to see what would happen, and the `Alt+F` shortcut key is effectively trapped by the text box before it reaches the menu, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: +1, better solution than mine. Didn't know about the Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key); trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi
if `You used WPF-Command` in your application you can use this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="YourCommnad"
              Gesture="CTRL+C" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: This not answers the question. The question is how to read a combination of keys in a textbox, not how to define hotkeys in XAML.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question of the original poster, this is in fact the answer I was looking for when I stumbled upon this thread through googling. So just want to let other people know, in 2016, this is a great solution to keybinding the entire window.